# Physical movement of documents with xquery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Can I physically move documents from one folder to other with xquery/Marklogic ? If yes, please explain in detail.

Comment: You need to tell us what you mean by "move". And by "folder" 

What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question. Why is "physical" movement important? The database abstracts the physical storage of documents away from the developer. If you're administering a MarkLogic database you can put the forests, the physical partitions where the data and indexes live, in different locations. I suspect that's not what you're asking, though. Can you please provide more details about the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

No.

To my knowledge the only XQuery functions in MarkLogic that access the filesystem directly are:

xdmp:filesystem-directory, 
xdmp:filesystem-file, 
xdmp:filesystem-file-exists, 
xdmp:filesystem-file-length,
xdmp:document-load,
xdmp:document-save

MarkLogic specifically does not let you exec commands or directly modify the host operating system's files.

Comment: I think derickson means `xdmp:save` instead of xdmp:document-save, and yes, that is the only function in MarkLogic that allows direct manipulation of the filesystem. So you *can* write files, but not delete. You can overwrite files with an empty one, but that only saves disc space. You could however interact with other services (using `xdmp:http-get` for instance), and have those do such work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I too am wondering what you mean by "move documents" ... are these MarkLogic documents or filesystem documents ?  And what is a "folder" in this context ? If this is a marklogic document do you mean to put the URI in a different "directory" ?

The closest thing to "physically move" of a marklogic document is to change its URI.
There is no builtin to do this but xmlsh supports this by copying some code on a mailing list long ago.  You can see the strategy here

http://xmlsh.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/xmlsh/extensions/marklogic/src/org/xmlsh/marklogic/resources/rename.xquery?revision=730&view=markup